# which: no java for my user on linux

Tags: java, linux

I try to install java8 on my Linux server centOS. In /etc/profile

```
export JAVA_HOME=/root/jdk1.8.0_71/
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin/:$PATH

[root@localhost ~]# echo $JAVA_HOME
/root/jdk1.8.0_71/
[root@localhost ~]# which java
/root/jdk1.8.0_71/bin/java
[root@localhost ~]#
```

And then I install Cassandra, but it cannot find the java8. And I execute some commands and get

```
[root@localhost ~]# su cassandra -c "echo $JAVA_HOME"
/root/jdk1.8.0_71/
[root@localhost ~]# su cassandra -c "whereis java"
java: /usr/bin/java /etc/java /usr/lib/java /usr/local/bin/java /usr/share/java /usr/share/man/man1/java.1.gz
[root@localhost ~]# su cassandra -c "which java"
which: no java in (/root/jdk1.8.0_71//bin/:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin)
```

I want to know since the PATH is right, why I failed to get java using which java?
And then I create soft link and change the mode of /root/jdk1.8.0_71 to 777

```
cd /usr/bin
java -> /root/jdk1.8.0_71/bin/java
```

But it is still not work. Did I miss somethings or make anything wrong?

Answer (score 2):

If the user Cassandra does not have permission on the /root folder then it wont be able to find it. **I don't know why would you copy the JDK in the /root folder.** My suggestion is to copy the jdk1.8.0_71 in the /opt folder and set the correct permission (owner or group), something like:

```
cp -r /root/jdk1.8.0_71 /opt
chown -R cassandra.cassandra /opt
```

Additional, setting paths in the PATH variable should not include the trailing to avoid "/root/jdk1.8.0_71//bin/"